# How to call controller's methods without refreshing the web page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I would like to know if there is a way to call a controller's method without having the whole page refreshed ?

My problem here is that I have a web form that look like this :

```
<form asp-action="AskDataGridHistByDay" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <input type="text" name="datefilter" id="datefilter" />
         </div>
         <div class="col-7"></div>
         <div class="form-check col-auto">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculer</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It calls AskDataGridHistByDay(string datefilter) method in my Home controller that look like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AskDataGridHistByDay(string datefilter)
{
     //Here I'm setting a static variable with the data from my model
     string datestart = datefilter.Substring(6, 4) + datefilter.Substring(3, 2) + datefilter.Substring(0, 2);
     string dateend = datefilter.Substring(19, 4) + datefilter.Substring(16, 2) + datefilter.Substring(13, 2);
     dataGridHistByDay = WebServiceCall.getInstance().GetDataGridByDayAsync(datestart, dateend).Result;
      return View("Index");
}
```

I know that I'm return a view so it have to refresh the page Index but I can't make a method that return nothing so I had to tell him to return a view because I don't have a cshtml file named AskDataGridHistByDay.

Do you know another way to send parameters to a controller so it doesn't call a or refresh my view ? 
Is there also a way in Javascript to call a method from the controller ?

Comment: you need to use ajax

Comment: It's best to not think of it as "calling a method". That's not how this works. You have to make a request to a route that invokes your action. *Nothing* happens without a request. However, by using AJAX, you can make requests without causing the page to refresh in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow steps below for a working demo:

1. Controller Action

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult AskDataGridHistByDay(string datefilter)
   {
       return Ok("Success");
   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   <form>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-4">
               <input type="text" name="datefilter" id="datefilter" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-7"></div>
           <div class="form-check col-auto">
               <input id="AskDataGridHistByDay" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Calculer" />
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>
   @section Scripts{ 
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#AskDataGridHistByDay").click(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: '/Home/AskDataGridHistByDay',
                       data: { datefilter: $("#datefilter").val() },
                       success: function (result) {
                           alert(result);
                       }
                   });
               });                  
           })
       </script>
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can make AJAX calls to the controller action. You just need to take care of the URL that the action method will be available at and what data you will return. It will be much better if your action returns JSON result if that is an MVC app. If that is a Web API, by default it will return JSON.

Refer official [Jquery page for AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)